# Azure Function app containerization consuming lot of memory

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-functions

In my current Infrastructure design, we are sharing app service with five other function apps. We are using a premium (EP1) plan for the same.

The plan is to containerize the function app. I was doing a POC on that and I observed each function consumes nearly 50-60% of memory and it is impossible to share the app service plan.
The future plan is to move the functional apps to K8s.

**Can we reduce the memory consumption or is it as expected?**
I wanted to check if can share the ASP plan for containerized FA to reduce cost before we move to K8s.
Also, I have noticed FA image size is around 200 MB (using dot net 7 isolated).

Comment: you could always deploy to container app. It is  managed k8s so you wont have the management/mintenance pain that come with it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deploy-container-apps?tabs=acr%2Cbash&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out and reporting this issue. You can leverage the **Memory Analysis** detectors available under the **Diagnose and Solve problems** section in the Azure function app portal blade as shown below:

[image]

Then click on the Memory analysis and Memory analysis for function app:

[image]

Alternatively, you can also check the memory consumption using the **Memory Working Set** metrics which shows the current amount of memory used by the Function App in MiB.

[image]

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/performance-reliability#organize-functions-for-performance-and-scaling) talks about the best practices for memory optimization in Azure Function app.

Hope this helps.